# Executing 2 shells at the same time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to execute 2 shells in jenkins at the same time? I need to start up my wildfly server in one shell, and execute maven commands in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent job that trigger 2 parallel builds that run the 2 jobs. Below an example:

[image]

TO have the trigger call builds on other projects install the below plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Does it makes sense?